# Which command is used by Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon Menu launcher to find the binary?

Tags: bash, linux-mint, cinnamon

In addition to emacs 27.1 which was installed by Synaptic Package Manager I have installed emacs 28.2.1 built from source.

Using `which` and `type` I am getting `/usr/local/bin/emacs` as the full path to the executable.

Because of this above I am expecting that launching emacs from main Cinnamon Menu will launch the binary reported by `which` and `type`, but it doesn't.

Using `type -all emacs` I see:

```
emacs is /usr/local/bin/emacs
emacs is /usr/bin/emacs
emacs is /bin/emacs
```

and the by the menu launcher started emacs is the /bin/emacs or /usr/bin/emacs (both are links pointing to the same executable).

Also `/usr/bin/env emacs` launches the /usr/local/bin/emacs binary.

In this context my question is:

**Which shell command can I use instead of `which` and `type` to get the actual full path to the binary used by the launcher of the main Cinnamon Menu?**

Answer (score 0):

The application "Alacarte" can do this with a gui. The command is

```
sudo apt install alacarte
```

After installation, when you open the menu and type "alacarte" an option called "Main Menu" will appear. On opening it you'll see a breakdown of all the sections of the menu and their contents. You can right-click an item and choose properties, and then edit the command from there.

Comment: No need to install alacarte to get to the properties of all Menu entries on my system (Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon). Right click on Menu, then Configure, then button [Menu] and finally button [Open the menu editor]. Anyway this hint *does not answer my question* at all, because my question asks for a command showing the search paths order Menu entries are using which apparently differs on my system from what the standard ways of getting this information deliver.